# How to syntax-highlight a part of file in a different syntax?

Tags: vim

I installed [bnf.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=250) (highlights BNF grammar files).

Suppose I have a comment in my code:

```
/* <BNF>

<S> := <A> | h
<A> := a | b | c | .

</BNF> */
```

Can Vim be somehow programmed to highlight that comment in BNF syntax, despite the filetype of the whole file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) for that.

Either explicitly assign the range, e.g.

```
:10,20SyntaxInclude bnf
```

or automatically based on the delimiting patterns:

```
:call SyntaxRange#Include('<BNF>', '</BNF>', 'bnf')
```

Comment: For `.vimrc`: 
`autocmd Syntax * if exists("b:current_syntax") | call SyntaxRange#Include('BNF {{{', '}}}', 'bnf    ')` — I changed `<BNF>...</BNF>` to `BNF {{{...}}}` to fold it easily.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your actual solution. Why do you check `b:current_syntax`?

Comment: If I don't, it prints `Error handling function SyntaxRange#Include..SyntaxRange#IncludeEx:
line 32:
E108: No such variable: "b:current_syntax"` when i execute `:help`. Maybe I should use different autocmd event?

Comment: @o2genum Ah, the problem is that `syntax/bnf.vim` doesn't set the variable (as all syntax scripts should). I'll also suppress the error in the next version of my plugin.

Comment: @IngoKarkat you should put your plugin on github so it can be easily fixed. having problems with it, and the vim-scripts repo is only cloning it from vim.org

Comment: @IngoKarkat Started an issue tracker here: https://github.com/fatso83/SyntaxRange/issues/1

Comment: @oligofren I'm not sure you'll get support from some arbitrary owner of a clone of my plugin. Additionally, you have a simple installation issue: you need my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) dependency, too. This is documented in the plugin's help.

Comment: Ah, I just did that as the the vimscripts site is terrible for issue tracking, and the Github mirror site (that people use with Vundle) did not have an issue tracker and I could not locate any github repo belonging to you :-) Makes it easier to find for others when google. For some reason the part of the Readme that deals with Installation is missing from the mirror site, that's why I did not see it.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Turns out the vimscripts github mirror was 2 years old, but I could not find a repo on your github page for the SyntaxRange plugin, only the ingolib. Could you push it to GitHub as well? Most people use Vundle or Pathogen to get libraries directly from source these days.

Answer (score 1):

for many file types vim will use the heredoc names as a clue. For example in php files I'm often creating here docs thus:

```
<?php 

$my_html = <<<html 
<h1>Solar</h1> 
<p>Is <em>good</em></p> 
html; 

$my_js = <<<javascript 
alert('yeah baby'); 
javascript; 

$my_sql = <<<sql 
SELECT user 
FROM mytable 
WHERE energy = 'solar'; 
sql;
```

works beautifully, with only problem being that indentation is problematic (the closing marker cannot have preceding spaces)

Answer (score 0):

My use case was highlighting an inline Lambda function in a CloudFormation template. Using the above-mentioned [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168), I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```vim
autocmd Syntax * call SyntaxRange#Include('vim: set ft=js:','vim: set ft=js:','javascript')
```

And then in my template:

```yaml
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: myFunction
      Code:
        ZipFile:
          !Sub |
            // vim: set ft=js:

            const aws = require('aws-sdk');
            const aws4 = require('aws4');
            const https = require('https');
            const zlib = require('zlib');

            ...

            // vim: set ft=js:

# vim: set ft=yaml:
```