# Mixing two syntax highlighting scripts

Tags: vim

I write blog posts with Jekyll, and for that I end up using three different languages in the same file: YAML at the start for post metadata, Markdown in the body, and C++ in code snippets.

I tried to setup a script so that I can have vim highlight all three properly for me, and ended up with something like this in syntax/jekyll.vim:

```
" Build upon Markdown syntax
runtime! syntax/markdown.vim

" pretend there's no syntax loaded
unlet b:current_syntax
" Bring in YAML syntax for front matter
syntax include @Yaml syntax/yaml.vim
syntax region yamlFrontmatter start=/\%^---$/ end=/^---$/ keepend contains=@Yaml

" pretend there's no syntax loaded
unlet b:current_syntax
" Bring in C++11 syntax for code snippets
syntax include @Cpp syntax/cpp.vim
syntax region cppCodeSnippet matchgroup=Comment start=/^{% highlight cpp %}$/ end=/^{% endhighlight %}$/ keepend contains=@Cpp

let b:current_syntax='jekyll'
```

I also set up a file detection script to set `ft` to this syntax.

It *almost* works. When I open a file that gets detected as this type, I get everything correct *except* for the C++ highlights. However, if I type `:syn on` after that, everything works fine. I can delete the buffer and open the file again and all highlights are ok. If I close vim and start it again, I need to run `:syn on` again.

What am I missing? How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Have you run any of the `:verbose se ft? syntax?`? Can you find out (using `:debug`?) which (Syntax) autocommands got fired in which order upon loading the cpp buffer? Does adding `:syntax sync fromstart` change things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to syntax-highlight a part of file in a different syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162221/how-to-syntax-highlight-a-part-of-file-in-a-different-syntax)

Comment: Sounds like a load order issue to me. If I had to guess I would say that something is loading after cpp.vim which is causing it to work the second time around. You could try adding cpp.vim to after which will probably tell you if it's a load order issue. You also might want to do :verbose set eventignore? in addition to ft? and syntax?. Otherwise, you can debug it using echom and :messages.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick fix:** append `syntax on` to the last line of your `.vimrc`, which is the same as setting `:syn on` in the live session.

**Not So Quick:**

Looks like you might have installed the custom 'jekyll' syntax alongside the default syntax files in `$VIMRUNTIME`.

According to [Vim wiki section on custom syntax](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files#Install_the_syntax_file), it's preferable to keep all personal customizations within `~/.vim`. For example, putting your `jekyll.vim` syntax in `~/.vim/syntax/`.

> Do not use a directory containing the files distributed with Vim because that will be overwritten during an upgrade (in particular, do not use the $VIMRUNTIME directory).

In the [Vim syntax docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html):
`:syntax enable` runs ':source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/DEFAULT_SYNTAX.vim'.
`:syn on` (or `:syntax on`) will "overrule your settings with the defaults".

So if setting `:syntax on` makes your custom syntax work, it must be contained in the default syntax set.

Try keeping all the custom stuff in `~/.vim` and see if that settles things.